# How to decrease the font size (zoom out) in Dillo?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fonts, browser

Is there an easy way to decrease the font size or simply zoom out in the Dillo browser? The standard shortcuts like <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> don't work.

I cannot find anything related to my problem on [their website](http://www.dillo.org/dillo3-help.html).

I've checked `~/.dillo/keysrc` and it is not possible to configure it there.

Comment: You're right, Dillo doesn't support zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://lists.dillo.org/pipermail/dillo-dev/2013-January/009779.html) suggests that it is not implemented. They say that they usually tinker with CSS to simulate *zoom out*.

[Ipor Sircer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182562/ipor-sircer) confirmed in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324507/how-to-decrease-the-font-size-zoom-out-in-dillo#comment570926_324507) that zooming is not implemented at the moment.